# Reference XSLT from jar using Saxon ANT task

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ant, saxon

I'm using Saxon's ANT task to apply an XSLT to an XML. Following is the ANT target I've created :

```
<target name="applyXSLT">
    <xslt in="${srcXML}" basedir="in/xml" destdir="out/xml" style="${basedir}/src/main/templates/xslt/stylesheet.xslt">
        <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
        <!-- All necessary varibles have been defined before -->
    </xslt>
</target>
```

It works fine when the XSLT is placed in the said folder inside the project. But now, I need to package the XSLT as a part of a jar, to be able to distribute the code to a third party client. I jar'd the XSLT, but now am unable to reference it (even after removing the `{basedir}/` ). Is there a different way to reference XSLT's that are a part of a jar while using Saxon?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the URL format

```
jar:///some/dir/!path/within/jar/stylesheet.xsl
```

Saxon recognizes this but I've no idea if Ant passes it through.

Otherwise, I think you'll have to unzip the JAR first into a temporary directory and then run the transformation from there.

Comment: Took the route of unzipping the JAR, and it worked. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `style` tag rather than the `style` attribute, allowing you to specify any valid Ant resource. To reference a file within a JAR, you can use the `javaresource` tag. The following example would find the XSL file within a JAR in your `master-classpath`; you can explicitly specify a JAR file instead, if you prefer, by defining a new `classpath` inline.

```
<target name="applyXSLT">
    <xslt in="${srcXML}" basedir="in/xml" destdir="out/xml">
        <style>
            <javaresource name="path/within/jar/to/stylesheet.xslt">
                <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
            </javaresource>
        </style>
        <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
        <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
        <!-- All necessary varibles have been defined before -->
    </xslt>
</target>
```

Some more details on `javaresource` [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#javaresource).